# Less Namespaces Pseudo and Other Selectors

Tags: css, less

How do you refer to a namespaced class with a pseudo selector?

```
#Namespace{
    .class:focus{
        prop: value;
    }
    .class + .class{
        prop: value;
    }
}

.anotherClass{
    #Namespace.class:focus(); //this does not work
    #Namespace.class:focus; //not working
    #Namespace > .class:focus(); //this does not work
    #Namespace > .class:focus; //not working
    #Namespace > .class + .class; //not working either
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### # pseudo-selectors:

In short: you can't. Only `id` and `class` (i.e. `#` and `.` respectively) selectors can be used as mixins. Pseudo and tag selectors cannot. See [Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature).

If you're planning to re-use some styles just define those as a (parametric) mixin:

```
#namespace {
    .whatever-suitable-name() {
        prop: value;
    }

    .class:focus {
        .whatever-suitable-name();
    }
}

.anotherClass {
    #namespace > .whatever-suitable-name();
}
```

#### # .class + .class:

> `#Namespace > .class + .class;` // not working either

Partially because of above (i.e. not every selector can be used as a mixin), but in this particular case you actually still can access that selector combination. Though the only ["officially recommended"](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-namespaces) syntax for invoking a namespaced mixin is: `#namespace > .mixin`, unofficially: "combinators" (e.g. `>`, `+`, `~`, whitespace etc.) are essentially ignored when compiler matches selectors for a mixin call, so:

```
#namespace {
    .class + .class {
        prop: value;
    }
}

.anotherClass {
    #namespace > .class > .class; // OK
    #namespace .class .class;     // OK
    #namespace.class.class;       // OK
    #namespace.class > .class;    // OK
    // etc.
}
```

See also [#1205](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1205).